# .Net NNTP implementation

Tags: .net, protocols, nntp

Is there a good `.Net` implementation of the `NNTP` protocol?

Answer (score 3):

Try libraries like http://sourceforge.net/projects/dougnewsnntp/ and http://www.codeplex.com/nntpclientlib

Answer (score 1):

There is a C# tutorial for reading posts using NNTP [here](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial212_Developing-an-NNTP-Newsgroup-Reader.html).  It should be enough to get you started but if you wish to start getting into processing binary posts, you're probably going to have to deal with some mime-type content too.  I don't think this article covers that.